Shadowsocks not accepting calls
I have docker-compose.yml:
version: '3'
services:
  shadowsocks:
    image: shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev:latest
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Moscow
      - PASSWORD=<psw>
      - METHOD=aes-256-cfb
      - ARGS=--fast-open
    ports:
      - "8388:11110"
      - "8388:11110/udp"
    restart: unless-stopped

It's logs:
 2024-08-27 09:19:09 INFO: using tcp fast open
 2024-08-27 09:19:09 INFO: UDP relay enabled
 2024-08-27 09:19:09 INFO: initializing ciphers... aes-256-cfb
 2024-08-27 09:19:09 INFO: Stream ciphers are insecure, therefore deprecated, and should be almost always avoided.
 2024-08-27 09:19:09 INFO: using nameserver: 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
 2024-08-27 09:19:09 INFO: tcp server listening at 0.0.0.0:8388
 2024-08-27 09:19:09 INFO: udp server listening at 0.0.0.0:8388

So, i supposed that shadowsocks works
But any attempt to connect there fails
I tried different clients (for android, for linux, gui for linux)
I keep getting this error
[stdout] 2024-08-27T09:25:07.744378887+03:00 ERROR socks5 tcp client handler error: Connection refused (os error 111)  

If to try to call shadowsocks from vds:
$ curl -v 0.0.0.0:11110
*   Trying 0.0.0.0:11110...
* connect to 0.0.0.0 port 11110 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 11110: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 11110: Connection refused

